# Are conditions equaivalent that they are roots of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If I have conditions that $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=|z_4|=1$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=0$

Is it suffice to state they are roots of unity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For an $n$th root of unity we must have $z_1=e^{2k\pi i/n}$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. So if $z_1=e^i$, it is not an $n$th root of unity for any $n$ (because $\pi$ is irrational), but still $|z_1|=1$. Let $z_2=iz_1$, $z_3=-z_1$, $z_4=-iz_1$ to have four distinct nonroots of unity that add up to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=re^{iy}$ where $r\ge0,y$ are real

$\implies|z|=r$

So, if $|z|=1,r=1\implies z=e^{iy}$

So, $z$ is  $\dfrac{2\pi}y$th root of unity

Comment: I don't know why $z$ is $\frac{2\pi}{y}$ th root ? could you explain it ??

Comment: @MariuszCzarnecki, As $e^{2\pi i}=\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=?$

Comment: $\;\frac{2\pi}y-$ th root doesn't have much meaning, at least in usual complex analysis, unles that is a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Since we're interested in nth root of unity so, $$x^n=1$$

$$x^n-1=0$$

Now we can use product of roots $=-1$ and other conditions depending on degree of polynomial.